# how to constrain the lifetime when doing unsafe conversion

Tags: rust

I want to create a `Test` ref from the array ref with the same size and keep the lifetime checking.
I can do this by using a function and I know the function can deduce the lifetime. The code below is intentionally designed to fail when compiling because of use after move. It works.

```rust
struct Test {
    a: i32,
}

/// 'a can be removed for simplification
fn create_test<'a>(ptr: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a mut Test {
    assert_eq!(ptr.len(), size_of::<Test>());
    unsafe { &mut *(ptr as *mut [u8] as *mut Test) }
}

fn main() {
    let mut space = Box::new([0 as u8; 100]);
    let (s1, _s2) = space.split_at_mut(size_of::<Test>());

    let test = create_test(s1);
    drop(space);

    test.a += 1;
}
```

My question is how can I do this without declaring an extra function to constrain the lifetime.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut space = Box::new([0 as u8; 100]);
    let (s1, _s2): (&'a mut [u8], _) = space.split_at_mut(size_of::<Test>());
    let test: &'a mut Test = unsafe { &mut *(s1 as *mut [u8] as *mut Test) };
    drop(space);
}
```

such `a is not allowed.

Comment: Regardless of lifetimes annotations, you should be aware that `Test` has a larger alignment than `u8`, and so you'll be invoking undefined behavior by casting the reference

Comment: Like said by @FilipeRodrigues, your code is unsound. What you want is the function [`space.align_to_mut::<Test>()[0]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.align_to_mut).

Comment: thank you. I forgot the alignment. `align_to_mut` will return prefix and suffix as well. I think `&mut space.align_to_mut::<Test>().1[0]` is ok

Comment: @shenyushi Yeah, my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works. And it holds the borrowing check.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut space = Box::new([0 as u8; 100]);
    let layout = Layout::new::<Test>();
    println!("{}", layout.align());
    let (_prefix, tests, _suffix) = unsafe { space.align_to_mut::<Test>() };
    assert!(tests.len() > 0);
    let test = &mut tests[0];
    let (_, suffix, _) = unsafe { tests[1..].align_to_mut::<u8>() };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, but this is not needed either. Lifetimes are used to ensure safety *across function boundaries*. In the same function you can just ensure safety manually.

Theoretically, we would not need a borrow checker if the compiler could just inspect the called functions and follow the execution path to deterime whether we invoke Undefined Behavior. Practically, this can't be done because of problems like the Halting Problem and performance.

Comment: *Theoretically, we would not need a borrow checker if the compiler could just inspect the called functions and follow the execution path* - This is a common misconception. Borrow analysis stops at function boundaries not just for performance, but to allow a function's _signature_ (public API) to advertise its borrowing behavior. That way changing an implementation detail inside a function doesn't risk breaking unknown callers - if the new implementation breaks the contract, it just won't compile. Fainlly, such analysis wouldn't work with unsafe/FFI code, which is what the OP is dealing with.

Comment: @user4815162342 You're right about libraries breaking changes, but I wanted to make the point that Rust's safety does not rely on lifetimes inside one functions obvious (if lifetimes are the `'a` and not the actual lones). About unsafe code, yes, but again I wanted to make a point.